# Entity-Attribute Data Models (like MS Common Data Model) for Industrial Automation and Manufacturing domains

Tags: architecture, attributes, entity, physical-design

Are there other (well curated!) Entity-Attribute Data Models like Microsoft Common Data Model or Common Information Model that can help me accelerate application development for Industrial Automation, Industrial, Automotive, Machinery domains.There are multiple sources for Ontology, Data Model Specifications but not many/any (at least I could not find) source with domain specific semantic data. Any clue in the right direction will be of great help. Thank you!

PS: I tried search engines (of course!), Wikipedia, talked to experts, researched papers/white papers etc. I ran into many sources for Ontology, Conceptual/Logical Data Model Specs, etc. but not domain specific Entity/Object/Thing and respective Attributes/Characteristics at a Physical level (or even close).

Comment: This isn't my domain but trying to help. I found a few packages that seem to include a data model. Including here incase it helps further your research. DBMS: https://www.isa.org/standards-and-publications/isa-publications/other-technical-resources/software  Repository of packages (perhaps less useful): https://opcfoundation.org/products/